# Blank line coming when i am using line feed

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML is like as show below:

```
<Description>
<LongDescription>a</LongDescription>
<LongDescription>b</LongDescription>
<LongDescription>c</LongDescription>
</Description>
```

And the desired output is:

```
<Description>
<LongDescription>a
 b
 c</LongDescription>
</Description>
```

I am using the below code to fetch the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Description">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::LongDescription)]" />
      <LongDescription>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LongDescription/text()" />
      </LongDescription>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LongDescription/text()">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But using this i am getting the result as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Description>
<LongDescription>
a
b
c</LongDescription>
</Description>
```

I want "a" to come besides the LongDescription not in the next line.

I have tried using strip and normalize option but it's not working.

but these options are not working.

Can anyone help me on this as soon as possible.

Thanks in Advance,
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the new line in LongDescription

```
  <LongDescription><xsl:apply-templates select="LongDescription/text()" />
  </LongDescription>
```

This template is a bit strange, should it be that way:

```
<xsl:template match="LongDescription/text()">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply , i tried this but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Description">
        <xsl:copy>
           <LongDescription>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="LongDescription/text()" />
            </LongDescription>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="LongDescription[1]/text()" priority="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LongDescription/text()">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Description>
   <LongDescription>a
b
c</LongDescription>
</Description>
```